# Problems with ng-repeat, $scope, $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs

im working with AnuglarJS 1.4.8. I want give out the data with ng-repeat.

I have the following problem and i have no more ideas to solve it. I tried the solutions from AnuglarJS but i doesnt work.

Could someone help me please.

> Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
>
> Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
>
> http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D

Service:

```
.service('database', function ($http) {
  self = this;
  this.url = 'http://localhost:3001';
  this.getPersons = function(cb){
      return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: self.url + '/loadperson'
      }).success(function (data) {
        cb(data);
      });      
    };   
});
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('myApp')
 .controller('personCtrl', function ($scope, database) {
   $scope.people = function(){
      return{
        getAll: function () {
          database.getPersons(function (data) {
            return data;
            // should return a Object(id, name)
         });
       }
    }
 };
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="people in people().getAll()">
    <p>{{people.name}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you put any watcher inside your controller?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the non-blocking way of javascript. Try following, it should work
Controller:

```
angular.module('myApp')
 .controller('personCtrl', function ($scope, database) {
   $scope.loadPeoples = function(){
      return{
        getAll: function () {
          database.getPersons(function (data) {
            $scope.peoples = data;
            // should return a Object(id, name)
         });
       }
    }
 };
 $scope.loadPeoples();
})
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="people in peoples">
    <p>{{people.name}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Almost there - just have to fix the `ng-repeat` declaration to access the `peoples` field.

Comment: Damn copy paste mistakes. Thanks. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try that.

Service:

```
.service('database', function ($http) {
  self = this;
  this.url = 'http://localhost:3001';
  this.getPersons = function(){
      return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: self.url + '/loadperson'
      });      
    };   
});
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('personCtrl', function ($scope, database) {
   database.getPerson().success(function(data) {
      $scope.people = data;
   });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="person in people">
    <p>{{person.name}}</p>
</div>
```

You should also be aware that you shouldn't return each time a NEW array for iterating. Otherwise angular will keep calling that function for retrieving a "stable" value for the array.

Comment: How i can store the object?

Comment: By storing it inside the `$scope`. And returning always the same instance.

Answer (score 0):

You've made a common error in javascript when running asynchronous queries. The pattern goes:

```
function outerFunction() {
    invokeInnerFunction(function() {
       return 3;
    }
}
```

What does `outerFunction()` return? An error is to think it returns 3, but the answer is actually that `outerFunction` doesn't return anything.

Likewise, in your example `getAll` isn't actually returning anything; it's just calling an asynchronous method. This asynchronous method invoked $http, which triggers a digest loop which will result in `getAll` being called again, and so on for ever. Be thankful that angular can detect this problem.

You only want to call the database query once on startup, and initialize the list of people. Simply store this list in a variable so it won't query the database again on the next digest loop.

```
angular.module('myApp')
 .controller('personCtrl', function ($scope, database) {
   $scope.allPeople = [];
   database.getPersons(function(data) {
      $scope.allPeople = data;
   });
 };
```

An then for your HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="people in allPeople">
    <p>{{people.name}}</p>
</div>
```

Much simpler.

Comment: How i can store this 'People' without calling this function again? When i refresh the Site all Objects gone, right? I find nothing in the AngularJS docs

Comment: @kicki: When you refresh the `page` all objects will be gone. But that happens in an single-page application.

Comment: @kick - but, when you refresh the page, the controller function will be invoked again, querying `allPeople` from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making a separate function to fetch the entities from the data base, then put this data in a variable, that you then will pass to the ngRepeat ?

your controller

```
angular.module('myApp')
 .controller('personCtrl', function ($scope, database) {
   $scope.people = [];
   $scope.getPeople = function(){
      return{
        getAll: function () {
          database.getPersons(function (data) {
            $scope.people = data;
            return;
            // should return a Object(id, name)
         });
       }
    }
   //load the list of people
   $scope.getPeople();
 };
```

your view

```
<div ng-repeat="person in people">
    <p>{{person.name}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Study this code and ask yourself... what does `getAll` actually return?

Comment: ah yeah you're right, I forgot to update the function. Thanks